Login to LinkedIn with `requests.session` and avoid initial load animation
This is what I get without logging in when I requests.get('https://linkedin.com'):

This is how I login:
import requests
from lxml import html

session = requests.session()
response = session.get('https://linkedin.com')
etree = html.fromstring(response.content)
session.headers.update(
    {
        'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'origin': 'https://www.linkedin.com',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'priority': 'u=0, i',
        'referer': 'https://www.linkedin.com/',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
        'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    }
)

data = {
    'loginCsrfParam': etree.xpath('//input[contains(@name, "Csrf")]')[0].value,
    'session_key': EMAIL,
    'session_password': PASSWORD,
    'session_redirect': '',
}

session.post(
    'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login-submit',
    data=data,
)

It logs in (username is present in response) but any subsequent requests give responses with the initial load animation which looks like this:

Under unclear circumstances and without changing anything in the code above, it sometimes works and gives the proper response which doesn't contain the animation. Is there an explanation / a way to prevent this from happening?
